# Invariant factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups

So I was asked the following question: Let $ G = \{ 1 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +a_3x^3 : a_i \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \} $, and define a binary operation on $ G $ by $ p(x) * q(x) = p(x)q(x) \bmod{x^4} $. This makes $ G $ a $ \mathbb{Z} $-module. Find the invariant factors of $ G $.

I understand that the operation makes $ G $ a finite abelian group ($ \mathbb{Z} $-module) hence we can apply the classification theorem. If I can find a set of generators and all possible relations between them then I know how to find the invariant factors. But I'm not sure how to do this. Any hints?

Comment: Is $\mod 4$ correct? Then you have $(1+x)^2 = 1+2x+x^2$, but this isn't in $G$ (as we have $a_1 = 2\neq 0$ or $1$).

Comment: Your edit hasn't fixed anything --- $(1+x)^2$ still isn't in $G$.  Additionally, do you intend $x^4 = 1$ or $x^4 = 0$?  The second one doesn't make sense (as $0\not\in G$), but how you defined multiplication implies it.

Comment: Additionally, $x^4 =1$ has the issue that $(1+x)^4 = 1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4\equiv 1+x^4\equiv 0$, so this is yet again not in your group.  It may be easier to look at the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle x^4\rangle$, (or mod $x^4-1$ if you want that relation to hold) and then look at the units in this ring.  This clearly won't be everything, as depending on which relation you're working mod you'll have either $x$ or $1+x$ as a zero-divisor.  Without specifying this though, the problem is impossible to solve.

Comment: In that case, you have that $x\in G$, and $x^3\in G$, but $x\ast x^3 = x^4 = 0\not\in G$.

Comment: I believe they are not in $ G $, since they have to have a constant $ 1 $ in front of them?

Comment: Traditionally, notation such as $x$ implicitly hides constant factors of $1$.  To include those, we'd have that $1x\in G$, and $1x^3\in G$, but $(1x)(1x^3) = (1\times 1)x^4 = 1x^4\equiv 0\not\in G$.

Comment: No, I mean the elements are of the form $ 1 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3 x^3 $, i.e. there is a constant $ 1 $ in the sum, hence $ x $ and $ x^3 $ are not in $ G $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements we have are:
$$\{1,1+x,1+x^2,1+x+x^2,1+x^3,1+x+x^3,1+x^2+x^3,1+x+x^2+x^3\}$$
It can be useful to see what the subgroups $\langle g\rangle$ look like for all $g\in G$, as this gives us a good idea what to pick as generators.
Additionally, this is an abelian group of order $8$, so it's isomorphic to one of the following: $$\mathbb{Z}_8,\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2,\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$$

To distinguish these cases, it can be useful to find the order of some elements:
\begin{array}{cccc}
g & g^2 & g^3 & g^4\\\hline
1+x & 1+x^2 & 1+x+x^2+x^3 & 1 \\
1+x^2 & 1 &&\\
1+x+x^2 & 1+x^2 & 1+x+x^3 & 1 \\
1+x^3 & 1 \\
1+x+x^3 & 1+x^2 & 1+x+x^2 & 1 \\
1+x^2+x^3 & 1 \\
1+x+x^2+x^3 & 1+x^2 & 1+x & 1
\end{array}
This gives us a decent amount of information.
The big thing it tells us is all of the inverses in this group, and all of the orders.
We can see that $1+x$ and $1+x+x^2$ are two elements of order $4$ that aren't powers of a single generator.
So, one them is the other times the element of order $2$.
Now, note that:
$$(1+x)(1+x^3) = 1+x+x^3$$
So, if we fix $1+x = g$, and $1+x^3 = s$, we get that $|g| = 4$, $|s| = 2$, and that:
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 1+x & 1+x^2 & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x^3 & 1+x+x^3 & 1+x^2 +x^3 & 1+x+x^2+x^3 \\
1 & g & g^2 & g^3s & s & gs & g^2s & g^{3}  
\end{array}
Is how each element is expressed in terms of generators.

From here, it should be easy to establish the isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Can you clarify the statement about "powers of a single generator"? I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: @mathstudent_101 Essentially, for each element $g\in G$, I'm looking at the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$.  I knew beforehand that the group was ismorphic to one of the three I mentioned, so knowing the orders of the elements helps compute that.  Additionally, once we know $|g|$, we'll have $g^{|g|-1}$ in the table, which tells us the inverses of all the elements.