# Decomposition finite abelian group into invariant factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $a_i\in \{0,1\}$, $A=\{1+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_{31}x^{31}\}\subset \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} [x]$. Suppose $a(x),b(x)\in A$. Define the group law in $A$ by $a(x)•b(x)=a(x)b(x)$ modulo $x^{32}$. Clearly, $A$ is a finite abelian group.

My question is how to write $A$ into decomposition of invariant factors ?

My original idea was to try to consider the polynomials containing term $x$ and all of which should have order $32$. But in this way I have to consider at least for the polynomials contain the monomial $x^{15}$ the elements of which type should have order $4$. The monomials with power larger than $15$ clearly have order $2$. I think I might have made things complicated. The thing is some of those subgroups may overlap and the order of $A$ is relatively large.

[Invariant factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2497473) This post deals with similar problem of small order but I don't think it is helpful.

I think I get the answer. Just consider $1+x^n$ where $n$ is odd. In this way, we don't see any overlap. Then, just compute the order.Then you will find one subgroup of order $2^5$, one of order $2^4$, two of order $2^3$, four of order $2^2$, and the rest eight of order $2$.

Comment: [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295003/question-about-a-finite-abelian-group#4295003) was asked a few minutes ago and was closed for lack of context and effort.

Comment: You find them the usual way. This is a $2$-group. The number of direct summands in the decomposition is given by $A/A^2$; the number of summands of order at least $2^2$ is given by $A^2/A^4$. The number of summands of order at least $2^3$ is given by $A^4/A^8$, etc.

Comment: Not any old abelian $2$ group, @ArturoMagidin. A maximal abelian subgroup of the Sylow-$2$-subgroup of $GL(32,2)$ I reckon. I wonder what the others look like.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I do not understand what point you are trying to make. Regardless of where the group might come form or be isomorphic to, it is fairly straightforward to count the number of elements in $A^{2^k}$, and thereby find the cardinalities of $A^{2^k}/A^{2^{k+1}}$, and thus determine the primary divisors/invariant factors of *this* group.

Comment: Sorry, it just seems to me to be an "interesting" group: absolutely agree with your comment on how to find the invariants.